# get first url segment with a javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this `regexp` to extract instagram.com usernames

```
const matches = value.match(
            /^(?:@|(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?instagr(?:\.am|am\.com)\/)?(\w+)\/?$/
        );
console.log(matches[1])
```

It works fine with [www.instagram.com/username](http://www.instagram.com/username) but it doesn't work with [www.instagram.com/username?ref=google](http://www.instagram.com/username?ref=google)

How can I exact only the username from the url?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

alternatively, do not use regex. e.g.

```js
const url = "www.instagram.com/username?ref=google";
const oUrl = new URL("http://" + url);
console.log(oUrl.pathname.substring(1));
```

or

```js
let url = "instagram.com/username?ref=google";
if (!url.startsWith("http://") || !url.startsWith("https://")) {
  url = "http://" + url;
}
const oUrl = new URL(url);
console.log(oUrl.pathname.substring(1));
```

Comment: how to deal with urls with or without www and https:// ?

Answer (score 0):

The `$` at the end matches the end of the line, but the end of the username isn't necessarily the end of the line. To permit `?` after the username as well, use `(?:$|\?)` instead of `$`:

```
^(?:@|(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?instagr(?:\.am|am\.com)\/)?(\w+)\/?(?:$|\?)
```

https://regex101.com/r/pbpi74/1

Answer (score 0):

You can also try a non-regex way using **.substring**. You may find it cleaner than regex.

It works with both URLs.

```
let username = url.substring(
    url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, 
    url.lastIndexOf("?") > 0? url.lastIndexOf("?") : url.length
);
```

Check fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/whx5otvp/